# Group by users in django ORM

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-orm

I've a StudentAnswer model which stores the answer id given by the student(User) in a quiz. If the answer is correct then 1 marks else 0. I'm also ranking the users based on their marks in a particular quiz.

The model looks like this:

```
class StudentAnswer(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='user_question_answer', 
            on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True, blank=True)
answer = models.ForeignKey(QuizQuestionAnswer, related_name='user_answer', 
            on_delete=models.CASCADE)
quiz = models.ForeingKey(Quiz, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
marks = models.IntegerField()
```

This is the query I'm using to rank my users:

```
StudentAnswer.objects.filter(
        quiz__start_date__month=date.today().month).annotate(
        rank=Window(expression=DenseRank(), order_by=[F('marks').desc(),])
    )
```

A user will have multiple entries in table(number of questions he attempted in a month). I want to group by each user, add their marks and then rank them for that particular month and send the response.

How can I do this?

Comment: How are marks determined? Summing these up? Average? Maximum? Something else?

Comment: This is what I was looking for:

StudentAnswer.objects.filter(quiz__start_date__month=date.today().month).values(                    'user').annotate(marks=Sum('marks')).annotate(rank=Window(expression=DenseRank(), order_by=[F('marks').desc(),]))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can order the `User`s by the sum of the `marks` in reverse order, so:

```
from django.db.models import Sum
from django.utils.timezone import now

User.objects.filter(
    user_question_answer__quiz__start_date__month=now().month
).annotate(
    total_marks=Sum('user_question_answer__marks')
).order_by('-total_marks')
```

or for a specific `Quiz`:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

User.objects.filter(
    user_question_answer__quiz_id=quiz_id
).annotate(
    total_marks=Sum('user_question_answer__marks')
).order_by('-total_marks')
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).